# Rviz: Howto set radius of TF frame axes? (not Axis axes)

Tags: ros, rviz, frame, frames, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

If you add an "Axes" to Rviz, it's possible to set the length and radius of the RGB-colored axis.  Hower, if you add "TF" frames, you can only edit the marker scale (combined length and radius) for all frames of reference.

I would like to customize the display of the axes for each link frame (TF) e.g. increase the length, bbut decrease the radius.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?  including modifying the Rviz config or background code?

Thanks,
David.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50334/rviz:-howto-set-radius-of-tf-frame-axes?--(not-axis-axes)/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you see as transforms is a [rviz built-in display type](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/TF).

You'd have to take the source of that display type (in the [visualization stack](http://ros.org/wiki/visualization?distro=fuerte), be sure to choose the matching branch) and modify it to your needs.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1